# C++ set iterator removal

Tags: c++, stl, set

Is it allowed to erase an element pointed by iterator, and advance the same iterator in one line to go to next element?

```
set<int>::iterator it = S.begin();
while (it != S.end()) {
    if (shouldBeRemoved(*it)) {
        S.erase(it++); // is this line valid?
    } else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Is it allowed to erase an element pointed by iterator, and advance the same iterator in one line to go to next element?**

Yes, it is valid.

---

**Rationale:**

`it++` increments `it` so that it refers to the next element but yields a copy of its
original value. Thus, `it` doesn't refer to the element that is removed when `erase()` is called.
And in case of `std::set` only iterators to the erased element are invalidated.<sup>#1</sup>

You can consider this code example as a boilerplate code to remove an element to which your iterator is referring.

---

**References:**

For `std::set`,
<sup>#1</sup>**C++03 Standard 23.1.2/8:**

> Only iterators and references to the erased elements are invalidated

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's valid. The expression `it++` is fully evaluated before the function is called, so the function receives the previous value of `it`, but by the time that gets removed (and invalidated), the iterator has already been incremented.